# Intellisense for Angular2 HTML templates

Tags: visual-studio, angular, angular2-template

We've recently started to migrate to Angular2 from another framework, most of my component templates are not inline and are in separated HTML files.

Is there any plugin that would provide something like IntelliSense inside the HTML?

For example, it would be great to see a list of methods of the component, or a list of properties of an item of a collection iterated with a NgFor directive.

I have failed to find such a thing.

We are using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you haven't come across the latest visual code IDE.

You can go on to [Visual Studio](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to download the latest, I believe that only when you're using interfaces or classes, Intellisense will kick in. I encourage you to use this if you're into using this for your development.

Comment: Hello, i appreciate your input, and will have a look at visual code.
Howeever, switching IDE might not be approved by my managment. So a solution for VS 2015 would be better.

Comment: @Greenmachine, I went to do some extra digging and found out that many users took the update approach. They went to patch their VS 2015, [VS 2015 Patch 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs). 

From this finding, I realise that they included typescript in it's patch, I believe that by having Typescript installed within the IDE, intellisense should work.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello.
Yes, we do have this patch installed. 
But it does not provide typescript help in seperate html files.
Thank you

Comment: I see, hmm, I don't think there are any plugins now to help you achieve what you want to do now. The best way will still be to reference from your component by using your IDE split panes.

Comment: Thank you once more for your time

Answer (score -1):

You need to download VS Code and the Angular Language Service plug-in.